# Latest Pydev Installation in Eclipse OSX Fails

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm trying to install `pydev` on my personal computer.

I'm using macbook air `OSX 10.9.3`, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Version: `Indigo Service Release 2 - Build id: 20120216-1857`, and the latest `Pydev` on eclipse marketplace. I installed this on a macbook air with similar specs at work so I'm unsure of why I'm getting this error.

I'm getting the following error:

```
> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
> context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
> action=). Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile50104149858241110.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile50104149858241110.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6663235687975438958.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6663235687975438958.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile2611980259498099300.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile2611980259498099300.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8758709566927844102.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8758709566927844102.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile5675507849083298257.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile5675507849083298257.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7405430504668812268.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7405430504668812268.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1012440814594205566.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1012440814594205566.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8381394945935866781.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8381394945935866781.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1100867892527883371.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1100867892527883371.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile111585641444420855.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile111585641444420855.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1555696270956564265.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1555696270956564265.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1364079426653067896.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile1364079426653067896.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.6.0.201406232321.
> Error reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8499824653585187530.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8499824653585187530.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile104276363428243370.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile104276363428243370.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6506621831623886304.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6506621831623886304.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.mylyn,0.4.0. Error reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7579016361075999876.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7579016361075999876.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature,0.4.0. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile385840627809414345.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile385840627809414345.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.6.0.201406232321. Error reading
> signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile3888607110238889239.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile3888607110238889239.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7655418894040906770.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile7655418894040906770.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile583811809684522907.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile583811809684522907.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.6.0.201406232321.
> Error reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8185931388103389865.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile8185931388103389865.jar
> Problems downloading artifact:
> osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.6.0.201406232321. Error
> reading signed
> content:/var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6086266818168901230.jar
> An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
> /var/folders/dq/7y19zm754bb2tf3vlt8pqyq80000gn/T/signatureFile6086266818168901230.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://pydev.sourceforge.net/ :
PyDev requires Eclipse 3.8 or 4.3 onwards and Java 7! For older versions, keep using PyDev 2.x (use LiClipse for a PyDev standalone with all requirements bundled).

In Eclipse, in the "Install new software" window, uncheck "Show only the latest versions of available software" and select Version 2.8.2.2013090511

Comment: Or even better, update Eclipse to a version which is more recent :)